# Weird behavior causes my runserver to not respond

Tags: django

I've been having some very weird problems. Yesterday I updated my master branch on a project and after that, when I tried to do `manage.py runserver` the runserver wouldn't serve any page. I had to `ctrl + c` to exit the server and I would later receive this message.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53975)
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x2ec8488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/virtualenvs/designersenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in inner_run
    run(addr, int(port), handler)
  File "/home/marco/virtualenvs/designersenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 721, in run
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 227, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 286, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.handle_error(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 342, in handle_error
    import traceback
ImportError: No module named traceback
```

I found out by experimentation that erasing the database(sqlite) and recreating it with `syncdb and migrate` removed the issue, but once I add something to the models via the admin page, I would get the same error again, no pages would be served.

I also noticed that when this was going on, python starting to occupy around 40-60% of my CPU and RAM. I later noticed on the project folder, where database.db is located, a database.db-journal file would be created every 2-3 seconds, get deleted and then reappear. Googling didn't bring me any results so I am laying my hands on SO wisdom. Thanks.

Comment: are you running in a virtualized environment by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am running a virtualenv. Do you have anything on mind?

Comment: sorry for getting your hopes up, but I was thinking of a virtual machine, my suggestion was a long shot anyways. I had a very weird problem with a VM yesterday where I got pseudo-IO errors and weird python errors (due to the IO).

Comment: is it possible that the first request that you send to the development server gets in to an infinite loop while executing a database query and all subsequent requests have to wait for the first one to finish?

Comment: @akonsu when maximum recursion is reached the message explictly says so. I don't think the problem is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple months late but anyway, here is what my problem was:

A django app was messing up and getting stuck in a bug. I believe it was Django Cache Bot.
Cheers.

Comment: Do you recall what the bug was and how you discovered that this was the problem? I'm having a very similar error at the moment with runserver + celery. I'm using the django.core.cache to store some things, so I'm wondering if it is a problem of using celery+caching or whether there is a problem with another app I have. Any thoughts?

Comment: I found the bug going back on the commits and just realizing one of the funny lines was a about cache bot. When I commented out that part, everything ran fine. Not sure what really caused it, I just left it out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've been able to isolate my problem to a different issue (calling a hadoop-streaming job within my task) and [posted it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852961/manage-py-runserver-restarts-when-celery-map-reduce-tasks-are-running-somet) in case you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are running in a virtual enviroment. It's possible that it became corrupted while downloading. I would recreate it from scratch.

Also, check in that enviroment shell if you can import traceback and check outside the enviroment too. It may give you some clues.

disclaimer: this answer is 90% intuition, sorry :/