# './manage.py runserver' restarts when celery map/reduce tasks are running; sometimes raises error with inner_run

Tags: mapreduce, celery, fabric, django-celery, hadoop-streaming

I have a view in my django project that fires off a celery task. The celery task itself triggers a few map/reduce jobs via subprocess/fabric and the results of the hadoop job are stored on disk --- nothing is actually stored in the database. After the hadoop job has been completed, the celery task sends a django signal that it is done, something like this:

```python
# tasks.py
from models import MyModel
import signals

from fabric.operations import local

from celery.task import Task

class Hadoopification(Task):
    def run(self, my_model_id, other_args):
        my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_model_id)
        self.hadoopify_function(my_model, other_args)
        signals.complete_signal.send(
            sender=self,
            my_model_id=my_model_id,
            complete=True,
        )

    def hadoopify_function(self, my_model, other_args):
        local("""hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file hadoopify.py -mapper "parse_mapper.py 0 0" -input /user/me/input.csv -output /user/me/output.csv""")
```

What is truly baffling me is that the django runserver is *reloading* when the celery task is run, as if I had changed some code somewhere in the django project (which I have not, I can assure you!). From time to time, this even causes errors in the runserver command where I see output like the following before the runserver command reloads and is ok again (note: this error message is very similar to the [problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435242/weird-behavior-causes-my-runserver-to-not-respond)).

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0xa18cd14>
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 48, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rdm/Biz/Projects/Daegis/Server_Development/tar/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in inner_run
    run(addr, int(port), handler)
  File "/home/rdm/Biz/Projects/Daegis/Server_Development/tar/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 721, in run
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 224, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

I've narrowed the problem down to when calls are made to hadoop by replacing `local("""hadoop ...""")` with `local("ls")` which does not cause any problems with reloading the django runserver. There are no bugs in the hadoop code --- it runs just fine on its own when its not called by celery.

Any idea of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discussion about this on the fabric github page [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/534), [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/277) and [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/102). Another option for raising an error is to use the settings context manager:

```
from fabric.api import settings

class Hadoopification(Task):
    ...
    def hadoopify_function(self, my_model, other_args):
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            result = local(...)
        if result.failed:
            # access result.return_code, result.stdout, result.stderr
            raise UsefulException(...)
```

This has the advantage of allowing access to the return code and all of the other attributes on the result.

Comment: i like this even better! now i only need to write a UsefulException :)

Answer (score 2):

So after digging around in the fabric source code, I came to learn that django was reloading because my celery task, run within a fabric.operations.local command, was failing (which is hard to detect within the hadoop output puke-fest). When a fabric.operations.local command fails, [fabric issues a sys.exit](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/utils.py#L26) which caused celery to die and django to try and reload. This error can be detected by catching a [SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) within the hadoop tasks like this:

```python
class Hadoopification(Task):
    def run(self, my_model_id, other_args):
        my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_model_id)
        self.hadoopify_function(my_model, other_args)
        signals.complete_signal.send(
            sender=self,
            my_model_id=my_model_id,
            complete=True,
        )

    def hadoopify_function(self, my_model, other_args):
        try:
            local("""hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file hadoopify.py -mapper "parse_mapper.py 0 0" -input /user/me/input.csv -output /user/me/output.csv""")
        except SystemExit, e:
            # print some useful debugging information about exception e here!
            raise
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that there is some collision on the name of [Task](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/api/core/tasks.html?highlight=task#fabric.tasks.Task) in both celery and fabric. I'd suggest using something more like:

```
import celery
class Hadoopification(celery.task.Task):
    ...
```

And try and avoid any further collisions, if that hunch is good.

But really, fabric's local is pretty nieve, and is essentially just a subprocess.Popen, which you could try calling raw to also separate out anything but python stdlib.

Comment: collisions was an interesting idea. i looked into that by only running one celery process at a time and that didn't fix the issue. thanks for your help, though!